Sync Editor windows with Dedicated Terminal
I have several Python script files open in VSCode. Each has a dedicated terminal window/pane. Is there a way to sync these terminal windows to their associated files?
Meaning, if I click tab1, the terminal pane (in the bottom half) displays the tab1 dedicated terminal. And so on for tab2/terminal2.
